# Comparing individual elements of an array and hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have the following hash and array, both with 8 elements each:

```
{1=>"2.06", 2=>"2.10", 4=>"2.00", 5=>"2.10", 6=>"2.20", 8=>"2.10", 9=>"2.10", 12=>"2.04"}

["2.06","2.10","2.00","2.10","2.20","2.10","2.10","2.04"]
```

I need to verify that each array slot matches with the corresponding hash value. For instance, `array[0]` needs to equal the value of `hash[:1]`, `array[1]` needs to equal `hash[:2]`, etc. What I don't want is to compare `array[0]` to any other hash value other than `hash[:1]`, `array[1]` to any other value other than `hash[:2]`, etc. The hash and array values are both read in the exact order pictured, so that order doesn't need to change. If any of these pairs don't match, they shall fail and iterate to the next pair.

I tried making a nested loop which iterated through the array and hash. but what it did was compare every hash value to one array slot and then iterate to the next array slot and repeat (see my current output code). This is my code so far with pseudo-code I need:

```
array.each_with_index do |item, index|
  hash.each do |key, value|
    puts "Key: #{key}"
    puts "Index: #{index}"
    #if item[index] == key[:value1]
    #print pass, else print fail
    #iterate to next pair
    #if item[index+1] == key[:value2]
    #repeat
    #...
    #end 
  end
end
```

This is what my code currently outputs:

```
Key: 1
Index: 0
Key: 2
Index: 0
Key: 4
Index: 0
Key: 5
Index: 0
```

...

This is what I would need it to output:

```
Key: 1     
Index: 0
Pass
Key: 2
Index: 1
Pass
Key: 4
Index: 2
Fail
Key: 5
Index: 3
Pass
```

...

Comment: Does the output should go on like this: `:key=>6, :idx=>4 pass`, `:key=>8, :idx=>5, fail`, `:key=>9, :idx=>6, pass`, `:key=>12, :idx=>7, fail`? What if the hash is `{2=>"2.06", 3=>"2.10", 5=>"2.00", 6=>"2.10", 8=>"2.20", 9=>"2.10", 14=>"2.10", 16=>"2.04"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing an equality check for hash values and an array is easy:

```
puts hash.values == array
```

To do what you're trying to do, a nested loop isn't appropriate (it iterates over the entire `hash` for each element in `array` rather than comparing one to one). You can use `zip` to iterate over both in parallel:

```
array.zip(hash).each_with_index do |(av, (hk, hv)), ai|
  puts "Key: #{hk}"
  puts "Index: #{ai}"
  puts av == hv ? "pass" : "fail"
end
```

Output:

```
Key: 1
Index: 0
pass
Key: 2
Index: 1
pass
Key: 4
Index: 2
pass
Key: 5
Index: 3
pass
Key: 6
Index: 4
pass
Key: 8
Index: 5
pass
Key: 9
Index: 6
pass
Key: 12
Index: 7
pass
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/KeenPinkInversion)

Comment: Your second line answers the question, so why not stop there? I find what follows to be of dubious value. I'm sure your answer is correct, but I'd be more comfortable if Ruby's documentation for [Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values) stated that values were returned in the insertion order of their associated keys (same for `each_key`, `each_value`, `keys` and so on). Perhaps the second line of [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html) implies all those methods return values in key insertion order.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, great point; it appears hash keys [are ordered](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html). The second line alone doesn't tell OP what they're doing wrong and doesn't provide the desired output.

Comment: er, second paragraph (not line).

Comment: It's OK if you find what follows to be dubious, but to my mind, knowing when to use nested loops vs single loops is pretty fundamental knowledge. Can you specify what you find dubious? Maybe I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 h={1=>"2.06", 2=>"2.10", 4=>"2.00", 5=>"2.10", 6=>"2.20", 8=>"2.10", 9=>"2.10", 12=>"2.04"}
 a = ["2.06","2.10","2.00","2.10","2.20","2.10","2.10","2.04"]
 (0).upto(a.length) do |index|
    if a[index]==h[index+1]
       puts "key: #{index+1}"
       puts "index: #{index}"
       puts "Pass"
    else
      puts "key: #{index+1}"
      puts "index: #{index}"
      puts "Failed"
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you currently face is because the second loop isn't necessary.

```
array.each_with_index do |item, index|
  hash.each do |key, value|
  #     ^ this is not needed
```

Instead access the hash by providing the key based on the index.

```
# setup
hash = {1=>"2.06", 2=>"2.10", 4=>"2.00", 5=>"2.10", 6=>"2.20", 8=>"2.10", 9=>"2.10", 12=>"2.04"}
array = ["2.06","2.10","2.00","2.10","2.20","2.10","2.10","2.04"]
```

```
array.each_with_index do |array_item, index|
  key = index + 1
  hash_item = hash[key]

  puts "Key: #{key}"
  puts "Index: #{index}"
  puts array_item == hash_item ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'
end
```

The above prints out what you expect as your output. However if you don't need the index for anything other than accessing the hash you can offset it by one by doing the following:

```
array.each.with_index(1) do |array_item, key|
  hash_item = hash[key]
  puts "#{key}: #{array_item == hash_item}"
end
```

**References:**

- [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)
- [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-each)
- [`Enumerator#with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index)